# How to pass controller params to Liquid filters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, liquid

Liquid:

```
asset = {{asset_url | 'screenshot.png'}}
```

View:

```
<img src="{{asset_url | 'screenshot.png'}}" />
```

Helper:

I parse it as below:

```
Liquid::Template.parse(asset).render(asset, :filters => [TextFilter]).html_safe
```

text_filter.rb:

```
def asset_url(input)    
  AwsWrapper::S3Object.url_for("\[**asset_id**]\#{input}", [BUCKET_NAME])
end
```

I wanted to know how to pass [asset_id] from view to the text_filter so that i will form the url to get the image from s3

Answer (score 0):

Any params can be passed to filters  through registers.

```
Liquid::Template.parse(asset).render(replace_objs, :filters => [TextFilter], 
:registers => { :your_object => object }).html_safe
```

text_filter.rb:

```
def asset_url(input)    
  asset_id = @context.registers[:your_object].asset_id
  AwsWrapper::S3Object.url_for(#{asset_id}\#{input}", [BUCKET_NAME])
end
```